# What is the best way to play a UIImageView animation once and remove it from memory immediately after playing it?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm having a hard time removing my animation from memory. What is the best way to do this?

This is my animation code:

```
-(IBAction)animationOneStart { 

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:88];

for(int count = 1; count <= 88; count++)
{
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPic1_%03d.jpg", count];
UIImage  *frame    = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
[images addObject:frame];
}

loadingImageView.animationImages = images;

loadingImageView.animationDuration = 5;
loadingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //Repeats indefinitely

[loadingImageView startAnimating];
[images release];

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[images removeAllObjects];
[images release];
```

Comment: at the same place where you are doing : [images release];

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to release it anymore with ARC under Xcode 4.2! Update today :)

Comment: that's good to know.. but I need this to work in iOS 4, unfortunately!

Comment: It still does. ARC just adds the methods at runtime, rather than you implementing it manually. It has complete compatibility with every iOS version you can still develop for, it just makes your life easier. If you don't believe me, check Apple's docs:

Comment: "ARC works by adding code at compile time to ensure that objects live as long as necessary, but no longer. Conceptually, it follows the same memory management conventions as manual reference counting, by adding the appropriate retain, release, and autorelease method calls for you.

ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 ... and for iOS 4 and iOS 5."

Via http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226

Comment: Wow, thanks Dylan. Will this _really_ automatically remove the images from the memory though?

Comment: Yeah! I've done memory tests, etc, etc and it handles memory *BETTER* than I did before. It's a no-brainer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is not a callback to know when the imageView's animation is finished.  This is unfortunate, because it means that to remove the animation when the imageView is finished animating, you will need repeatedly check the imageView's `isAnimating` method until it returns false.  The following is an example of what I mean:

You might be able to do something like this—in your original code, add the following line

```
[loadingImageView startAnimating];
[images release];

[self performSelector:@selector(checkIfAnimationIsFinished) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.5f];
```

Then create a method

```
-(void)checkIfAnimationIsFinished {
    if (![loadingImageView isAnimating]) {
        [loadingImageView release];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkIfAnimationIsFinished) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
    }
}
```

This was just an example, I used the values 4.5f and 0.5f because, unfortunately, the timing is not precise, it is more of a ballpark figure.  4.9f and 0.1f might work better. Regardless, the problem is that if you set the method to fire 5.0f seconds after you start the animation, it is not 100% certain that the animation will be be finished or not. So you will need to check repeatedly if it is not finished.

Anyway, this is not the cleanest solution, but unless someone else knows how to get a callback when an imageView is finished animating, I don't know of a better solution.